# Not able to connect with multiple databases by using mongoose in nestjs framework

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I am getting errors while trying to connect multiple databases into nestjs framework. I am trying to connect with multiple databases using the mongoose module in nestjs framework. I have tried with single database it's working fine.

**Error**

This error I am getting if i am adding multiple MongooseModule.forFeature and MongooseModule.forRoot

```
[Nest] 3397  - 04/11/2022, 11:27:16     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 3397  - 04/11/2022, 11:27:16   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
[Nest] 3397  - 04/11/2022, 11:27:16     LOG [InstanceLoader] MongooseModule dependencies initialized +2ms
[Nest] 3397  - 04/11/2022, 11:27:16     LOG [InstanceLoader] MongooseModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 3397  - 04/11/2022, 11:27:16     LOG [InstanceLoader] HttpModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 3397  - 04/11/2022, 11:27:16   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AppService (?, Logger). Please make sure that the argument DeviceIdentityModel at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If DeviceIdentityModel is a provider, is it part of the current AppModule?
- If DeviceIdentityModel is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AppModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing DeviceIdentityModel */ ]
  })
```

**App.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { DeviceOnboardController } from './device-onboard/device-onboard.controller';
import { DeviceOnboardService } from './device-onboard/device-onboard.service';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
const config = require('./config');
import {
  DeviceIdentity,
  DeviceIdentitySchema,
} from './device-onboard/db/mongo/device_identity.schema';
import {
  userDeviceMap,
  userDeviceMapSchema,
} from './device-onboard/db/mongo/user_device.schema';
import { Logger } from './logger';
import { AuthenticationService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature(
      [
        {
          name: DeviceIdentity.name,
          schema: DeviceIdentitySchema,
          collection: 'deviceIdentities',
        },
      ],
      'iam',
    ),
    MongooseModule.forFeature(
      [
        {
          name: userDeviceMap.name,
          schema: userDeviceMapSchema,
          collection: 'device',
        },
      ],
      'User'
    ),
    MongooseModule.forRoot(config.database.iamMongodbConnection, {
      connectionName: 'iam',
    }),
    MongooseModule.forRoot(config.database.havellsOneMongodbConnection, {
      connectionName: 'User',
    }),
    HttpModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController, DeviceOnboardController],
  providers: [AppService, DeviceOnboardService, Logger, AuthenticationService],
  exports: [Logger],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import {
  DeviceIdentity,
  DeviceIdentityDocument,
} from './device-onboard/db/mongo/device_identity.schema';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { Logger } from './logger';

var redis = require('redis');
var config = require('./config');
const crypto = require('crypto');

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(DeviceIdentity.name)
    private devIdent: Model<DeviceIdentityDocument>,
    private logger: Logger,
  ) {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the connection name to the `@InjectModel()` as well as to the `MongooseModule.forFeature()`. So in your case that decorator should be `@InjectModel(DeviceIdentity.name, 'iam')`